# Education Loan interest paid & loan completed 2016 | india | How to claim income tax

Tags: income-tax, india, education

I bought education loan in 2006 and completed the loan with interest in March 2016, Is it possible to claim income tax against interest paid for this loan in FY 2017-2018 in India?

Answer (score 1):

Section 80E allows for deduction of interest upto 8 years. Deduction has to be in the year when payment is made.

Thus you can't claim it in next year.